# Sort multidimensional array with floats

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, floating-point

I have a multidimensional array with locations data (e.g. address, phone, name,..) and their relative distance from a certain point as floats (e.g. `0.49012608405149` or `0.72952439473047` or `1.4652101344361` or `13.476735354172`).

Now I need to sort this array so that it starts with the data set of closest distance (`0.49012608405149`) and ends with the farthest (`13.476735354172`).

The function I use so far does a good job, but messes up some times, which is of course as it uses strcmp

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a["distance"], $b["distance"]);
        }
        usort($resultPartner, "cmp");
```

I googled a lot but couldn't find anything for my case. If possible I would like to avoid a `foreach` statement, as I read it can have a poor performance with big arrays.

Do you have any idea/experience with that and can give me a working function for this? Thank you!

Comment: What is it sometimes 'messing up'? I have learned from my experience with C# that floats not very good numbers to compare and you should check if they're 'almost' the same instead of 'exactly' the same since they are quite inaccurate, which could maybe explain the 'messing up'

Comment: It messes up, because strcmp is a string comparison and therefore obviously not the right approach to sort floats. ;) But I didn't know better until now.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp()` is *binary safe string comparison*  why you don't just compare floats?

When comparing floats php manual says

> Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as
>   float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's
>   return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an
>   integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

So you must be careful.

Look at this: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

> Since floating point calculations involve a bit of uncertainty we can
>   try to allow for this by seeing if two numbers are ‘close’ to each
>   other.

Try something like this:

```
function cmpfloat($a, $b) {
 if (abs($a["distance"]-$b["distance"]) < 0.00000001) {
   return 0; // almost equal
 } else if (($a["distance"]-$b["distance"]) < 0) {
   return -1;
 } else {
   return 1;
 }
}
```

Following function is good if comparing integer values:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a["distance"] < $b["distance"] ? -1 : ($a["distance"] === $b["distance"] ? 0 : 1);
}
```

if a distance is smaller than b distance return -1
if a distance equals b distance return 0
if a distance is greater than b distance return 1

Reason:
`The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`

Comment: Thank you!! This works!! But one question, why did you add '? -1 :1' ? As far as I can see it, that only reverses the order. I did accomplish that also by just turning the '<' into '>'. But I am no php expert at all, so maybe you can explain it to me. Thank you anyways!!

Comment: @Sebsemillia i edited it more and put reason for that also. BUT there must be some enhancement done .. editing.

Comment: Thanks again for the update! I also read what the php manual said regarding to comparing floats, but they didn't show any alternative (or at least I didn't find them), that's why I asked this question here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in such way:

```
$data = array(
    array('dist' => 0.72952439473047),
    array('dist' => 0.49012608405149),
    array('dist' => 0.95452439473047),
    array('dist' => 0.12952439473047),
);
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $dist[$k]  = $v['dist'];
}
array_multisort($dist, SORT_ASC, $data);
```